# If I console.log(i) why do I get this answer?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I cannot understand why when I console.log(i) ina for loop I get this answer:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

 }

console.log(i)
```

answer is 3

But i is less than 3. Why would the answer would be 3?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The loop runs which makes `i` increase to `3` (`i++` is run three times)

Comment: To complement @IsmaelPadilla comment, check this Syntax > `final-expression` on this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: The condition of the loop makes it keep running until `i<3` is false ... if `i<3` is false, and it started at 0, incrementing by 1 each time, then clearly, the value for i is `0 ... 1 ... 2 ... 3 ...` at 3, the condition is false, therefore i is 3

Answer (score 1):

The `i < 3` in `for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)` means "keep running the loop as long as `i < 3` is true". It doesn't mean "magically keep `i < 3` true all the time no matter what happens to any variables".

Your `console.log(i)` is outside of the loop, so obviously, it won't get a chance to run until `i < 3` isn't true anymore.

Comment: To expand on this, a `for` loop is basically a convenience shorthand for a particular kind of `while` loop -`for (a; b; c) { /*loop body */}` is equivalent to `a; while (b) { /* loop body */ c; }`.